# 1000 W, 100 kHz power amplifier design

Tags: amplifier, power-amplifier

I am designing a power amp, input 10 Vpp, 100 kHz sinwave, maximum undistorted power output 600-1000W, output voltage over 50 Vpp.

This amp would be used as the source of guided wave in magneticstriction detection. So the output wave is desired to be sinwave or trianglewave.

I had simulated an OCL amplifier circuit  in class AB with distributed-element, but it doesn't perform well. The peak undistorted frequency is 20 kHz, and the max power is 100 W.

I find a power amp OPA462 from ti.com. The max output current voltage is 45 mA, 60 V under 100 kHz. I want to use it as the prime stage amp and build a class AB amp with distribute element to amplify current but I am not sure if it will work.

Does anyone have some ideas about this? Also is there any recommended learning material? I am new in power amp design and don't know where to find leaning material about this...

Thanks a lot.

Comment: you must define the acceptable level of distortion, because this will change matters a lot. if you want to build this in class AB, you are looking at a big device (est. 20 kg at least) with a lot of effort spent to cooling and thermal stabilization. in class D, this is arguably easier but needs a rather higher switching frequency in the ballpark of 10 MHz for very low distortion..Look at GaN parts.

Comment: How much of this have you ‘designed’ so far?

Comment: I  simulated an OCL power amp circuit, but it seemed not to work well....it can only work under 20khz, 100w. I tried to change its devices but still unable to achieve 100Khz, 1000w.

Comment: What is the impedance of the load? If it is inductive, phase shift between voltage and current will increase dissipation in the transistors, so it is important to know.

Comment: You need to think about the peaks of output current and whether your (many paralleled) output transistors can produce current peaks of around about 80 amps when driving the 1,000 watt load. Your power supply will need to be able to deliver over 90 amps of course. Have you considered these things?

Comment: I am afraid I haven't... Is there any learning material that would help me?

Comment: 100 kHz is not far from 'audio', and indeed a long time ago I bought some commercial rack mounted 'audio' amplifiers in the 'many-100-watt' ballpark that claimed to have a frequency response to 100 kHz. Invest an hour or two in searching to see whether this equipment is still commercially available off the shelf. It depends on your application whether you would want to use such kit. If it's a one-off to do your magnetostriction project, it's a no-brainer, don't spend time designing amplifiers. If you are planning to sell multiple systems, then your own design would keep the parts cost down.

Comment: if you can limit your 0-100 kHz to e.g. 20 Hz to 96 kHz, then you can use standard PA Equipment. available both in class AB and class D

Comment: If the load and frequency don't change too much, it might be better to just use a square wave and a filter to attenuate the harmonics. This will produce a very, very simple H-bridge hardware implementation.

Answer (score 1):

If the load impedance is reasonably similar to a loudspeaker, a few ohms resistive plus some inductance, then 100kHz sine wave could be done with the same type of design as a high power audio amplifier, perhaps with a bit more bandwidth, but that's okay.

However 100kHz triangle wave will be more difficult, because it contains higher harmonics and the amp has to process them, which means it needs a higher full power bandwidth (not just small signal bandwidth).

For example here's a quick model of 100kHz triangle with 500kHz brickwall lowpass applied. It still looks reasonably triangular, but the corners are rounded of course. So you probably can get away with bandwidth below 1MHz, maybe 500kHz.

[image]

At this power level, the natural choice would be class D. However, class D amps use a lowpass output filter of course. To get the bandwidth you need for that 100kHz triangle, the cutoff of that filter will have to be a few hundred hKz, that's 10x higher than the usual (cheap, and already available) audio designs so you cannot use any standard audio design. And the switching frequency will have to scale accordingly, which means you'll probably have to use GaN FETs, not to mention the layout will require a specialist. That's the case for everything class D, but the higher the switching frequency, the harder it is.

For a one-off design, I'd see two options:

- Standard class-AB

This is basically a high power audio amp, so you will find material online. In fact, you could use a high power class AB PA amp and modify the input filter to extend its bandwidth, that could be a simple solution. It will only work if the load is reasonably similar to a loudspeaker though. From what you say, 1kW at 50Vpp (25V peak) implies a load resistance below 0.5 ohms, which means the voltage/current design points of an audio amp designed for 4-8 ohms will be wrong. It will have too much voltage and not enough current. If it can deliver the current, then it will have too much voltage headroom, which means dissipation in the output devices (Vds*Id) will be many times higher than what it should be if the power supply voltage was designed to suit your load.

So... Output devices can't be bipolars, because they're too slow at switching off at this kind of current and frequency. So that leaves vertical MOSFETs that work in linear mode and aren't prone to Spirito effect, that is IRFP240/9240, that's pretty much the only choice.

So, first pick a supply voltage, that will need to be about 7 volts higher than the desired peak output voltage. You'll need a pretty beefy power supply ; fortunately you should be able to get some LLC resonant power supply blocks for high power audio amps with the kind of voltage and current you need at reasonable price from ConnexElectronics. Otherwise, use ready made SMPS. Don't bother with a huge transformer, a regulated switching supply is really nice. It also results in lower dissipation, because a regulated supply voltage means you get away with lower voltage headroom.

Then you should make a model of your load, then load that in Spice and calculate the peak and average power dissipation in the output devices depending on output voltage, current, frequency, etc. Max dissipation does not occur at full power because the voltage across output devices is lower. Instead it occurs at something like 1/2 to 2/3 output power, depending on voltage/current phase shift. That's when the product of voltage across devices and current is highest.

If the thing is expected to output full power continuously, allow about 50-70W per TO-247 device. So you will end up with maybe 10-15 pairs. Fortunately they are very cheap so you can use a lot of them in parallel.

Next is thermal design, so in the step above you calculated max dissipation, so now you calculate the heat sink you need in °C/W. It'll probably be something ridiculous like 0.1°C/W which means a large thick tunnel heat sink with a powerful fan. Basically look at teardowns of Class-AB PA amps in that power range online, look how it's done inside. Use Keratherm 86/82 as thermal interface material, the average silpad will not do.

So now you have a PCB attached to the heat sink. You need 0R22 non inductive source resistors (ie, 5x 1R 1W SMD resistors) for current balancing, on the PCB, with squishy thermal interface pads to the heat sink.

The slew rate of your triangle wave is very low (5V/µs) so no problems there.

Thermal compensation isn't a problem with these FETs, a simple Vbe multiplier will work. If you want the details, read the book about power amplifiers by Bob Cordell. If you go on this project, it's a must read.

All these MOSFETs will have quite high gate capacitance, so you can't drive them with an opamp. It will not have enough output current. You will need rather beefy drivers, and if the amp oscillates (which it will do during testing) then drivers that are wimpy will run out of SOA and burn. Fortunately, voltage is pretty low, so you can use fast medium power transistors like 2SA2039/2SC5706.

You can drive these drivers with your opamp, although compensation would probably be easier with a standard class-AB discrete frontend.

- Solution #2: Class D

Since you speak of magnetostriction, the load is probably going to be a coil. If there is someone who can do this sort of layout in your team, you could use a class D design, using the load coil as the output coil, without any output filter.

In this case the amp would regulate current in the output coil directly, instead of voltage.

If you don't mind too much about distortion, then you can use a simple hysteretic scheme where the output current oscillates around the desired value.

Comment: Thanks so much, it helps a lot!

Comment: You're welcome! If you want to design it, I really recommend [Cordell's book](http://www.cordellaudio.com/book/) ; it's expensive but definitely worth it.

Answer (score 1):

An off the shelf solution is the model 1000S04 from a company called Electronics & Innovation based in Rochester, NY. The unit is rated for 1000 watts output from 20 to 400 kHz and is a class D design.